# Как вставлять символ в строку на каждые 50 знаков

Tags: python, строки

Нужно вставлять "\n" в строку на каждые 50 знаков.

Comment: Хм... А какие варианты Вы уже попробовали?

Comment: Пытался получать index каждого элемента и проверять остаток от деления на 50, если он равнялся 0, вставлять "\n"
 Не смог реализовать исключительно из за плохого знания языка.

Answer (score 3):

В стандартной библиотеке есть [удобный модуль для этого](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html):

```
from textwrap import wrap

s = 'Какая-то очень длинная строка'

wrapped_s = '\n'.join(wrap(s, width=50))
```

Или без дополнительного импорта:

```
def chunkify(items, chunk_size):
    for i in range(0, len(items), chunk_size):
        yield items[i:i+chunk_size]


wrapped_s = '\n'.join(chunkify(s, 50))
```

Но этот вариант будет разбивать именно по символам, а первый не будет разрывать слова.

Comment: дополнительная библиотека это не очень хорошо. 

Но в остальном ответ мне подходит. Это почти идеальный вариант, благодарю.

Comment: @DeniBravo это [модуль стандартной библиотеки](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html), ничего устанавливать не потребуется.

Answer (score 1):

В Pythоn вам нужен метод append и с его помощью вы можете реализовать цикл for, в котором вы на место каждого 50-ого элемента будете вставлять '\n'